# Attribute name must contain word characters only in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php

Tags: php, yii2

I have been having this error since yesterday and i can't find any solution. the error was in the `Technician No` attribute Label. I already changed the database field to 'number' but still no effect. I already changed the word `No` to Number in the attribute labels but still the same error. Do I need to code a validation exception about this matter? Can someone help me? thanks in advance.

I have this code for the model.

Techinicians.model

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'technician_no' => 'Technician No',
            'smcode' => 'Code',
            'name' => 'Name',
        ];
    }
```

and the controller:

```
public function actionTechnicians()
    {
        $model = new Technicians();
        return $this->render('technicians', [
            'model' => $model,
            ]);
     }
```

this is the ActiveForm in the View.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
          'id' => 'new-technician-form',
          'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
           ]); ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'Technician No')->textInput() ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'Code')->textInput() ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'Name')->textInput() ?>
<div class="form-group">
      <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'technicians-button']) ?>
 </div>
<div>
      <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']); ?>
 </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply use attributes names instead of labels :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'technician_no')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'smcode')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
```

Comment: so, I will disregard or omit the attributeLabels function?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ??

Comment: err, you same to use attribute names instead of labels so i thought maybe do I need to do something in the model. wait. i will try that one.

Comment: oh! now I get it! thank you! so that's why I'm getting that error.